# use PHP to fetch a complete object from Mongo although some objects have "missing" fields

Tags: php, json, mongodb

So, I have a following array of objects in my Mongo collection

```
[{  
  id: 1,
  fields: {a:"1", b:"2", c:"3"}
}, 
{
  id: 2,
  fields: {a:"2", b:"3", d:"4"}
}]
```

and using PHP I want to read it in as an array, so the empty fields in Mongo are prefilled as empty strings, and it looks like this

```
[{  
  id: 1,
  fields: {a:"1", b:"2", c:"3", d:""}
}, 
{
  id: 2,
  fields: {a:"2", b:"3", d:"4", c:""}
}]
```

Is there a way to do it without preprocessing the fields object, and saving all the keys.

Comment: you could instanciate one array filled with default values as "prototype" and use array_merge

Comment: but I dont know the list of possible keys in "fields" object, so how can I make the array filled with default values?

Comment: well, if you don't know what the fields are - how could the code know it?

Comment: I thought maybe based on the structure somehow. All fields are there.